# Get access to *_path helpers inside ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to call *_path methods (like `root_path`, `post_path`, etc) inside ApplicationHelper.

If call it directly, i get an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000002d94480>
```

Is there some convenient to do that?

Comment: Did you define a root path in your routes file?

Comment: Actually it was because I've been trying to call it through console using `helper` method. But thanks for reply, now I understand that `_path`  must work correctly inside helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to define root_path in config/routes.rb. For example,

```
root to: "shared_pages#home"
```